# Getting form data from POST and inserting to mysqli database

Tags: php, forms, post, mysqli, prepared-statement

Learning PHP and for my most recent assignment, I had to create an HTML form, use PHP for error checking, insert the data into a database using mysqli, and then retrieve the values and display them in a table.  I turned the assignment in even though I didn't have it working 100%, but I'm just trying to figure out where I've gone wrong while waiting for feedback from my instructor.  I've checked out several similar threads, but so far none of the solutions offered seem to work for me.

So far, my form works and it seems to redirect and connect to the database just fine.  It also retrieves data already stored in the database and displays it in a table.  But I can't for the life of me seem to get it to actually write the form data that gets submitted via POST.  Regardless of what data is or is not entered on the form, when the submit button is clicked, it writes a blank row to my database, which should be prevented by my error-checking.  So in addition  Here's my code for the form:

```
<?php
    include ("dbinfo.php");
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);

    //declare variables
    $errors = 0;

    //if form is submitted
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

        //store submitted values
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        $street = $_POST['street'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $province = $_POST['province'];
        $postal = $_POST['postal'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];

        //error checking routine
        if ( !isset($_POST[$title]) || empty($_POST[$title]) ) $errors = 1;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$firstName]) || empty($_POST[$firstName]) ) $errors = 2;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$lastName]) || empty($_POST[$lastName]) ) $errors = 3;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$street]) || empty($_POST[$street]) ) $errors = 4;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$city]) || empty($_POST[$city]) ) $errors = 5;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$province]) || empty($_POST[$province]) ) $errors = 6;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$postal]) || empty($_POST[$postal]) ) $errors = 7;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$country]) || empty($_POST[$country]) ) $errors = 8;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$phone]) || empty($_POST[$phone]) ) $errors = 9;
        if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ) $errors = 10;
        if ( !isset($_POST[$email]) || empty($_POST[$email]) ) $errors = 11;
    }

    //if error flag is still 0
    if ( $errors == 0 ) {
    
?>
<!-- display the form -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- if errors exist, display error message(s -->
        <p>
            <strong>Instructions:</strong> To complete your registration, please fill out the following form.
            <?php if ($errors > 0) echo "<p><font color=red><strong>Please ensure all required fields are filled.</strong></font></p>"; ?>
        </p>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="title" >Title</label>
            <select name="title">
                <option value="" <?php if (isset($title) && $title =="") echo "selected";?>></option>
                <option value="Mr" <?php if (isset($title) && $title == "Mr") echo "selected";?>>Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs" <?php if (isset($title) && $title == "Mrs") echo "selected";?>>Mrs</option>
                <option value="Ms" <?php if (isset($title) && $title =="Ms") echo "selected";?>>Ms</option>
                <option value="Dr" <?php if (isset($title) && $title =="Dr") echo "selected";?>>Dr</option>
            </select>
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($title) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["firstName"]) ? $_POST["firstName"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($firstName) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="">Last Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["lastName"]) ? $_POST["lastName"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($lastName) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="">Street Address: </label>
            <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="123 ABC Drive" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["street"]) ? $_POST["street"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($street) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="">City: </label>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Anytown" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["city"]) ? $_POST["city"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($city) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="">Province: </label>
            <input type="text" name="province" placeholder="Nova Scotia" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["province"]) ? $_POST["province"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($province) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="">Postal Code:</label>
            <input type="text" name="postal" placeholder="A1A 1A1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["postal"]) ? $_POST["postal"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($postal) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="country">Country: </label>
            <select name="country">
                <option value="" <?php if ( isset($country) && $country == "" ) echo "selected";?>></option>
                <option value="canada" <?php if (isset($country) && $country == "canada") echo "selected";?>>Canada</option>
                <option value="usa" <?php if (isset($country) && $country == "usa") echo "selected";?>>USA</option>
            </select>
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($country) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="555-555-5555" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["phone"]) ? $_POST["phone"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($phone) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="email">Email Address: </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : ''; ?>">
            <?php if ( $errors > 0 && empty($email) ) echo " <font color='red'><strong>*required</strong></font>"; ?>
            <br />
            <label for="newsletter">Subscribe to our newsletter? </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1">
            <br /><br />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php 
} else {
//redirect to database
    header("Location: regdatabase.php");
    exit;
}
```

My dbinfo file only contains $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, and $db_name.  This is the code for the regdatabase.php.

```
<?php
    include ("dbinfo.php");
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //establish a DB connection to a specific database
    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    //check for valid connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully. <br />";

    //prepare and bind
    $sql = "INSERT INTO registered_users (title, firstName, lastName, street, city, province, postal, country,  phone, email, newsletter)
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssi", $_REQUEST['title'], $_REQUEST['firstName'], $_REQUEST['lastName'], $_REQUEST['street'], $_REQUEST['city'], $_REQUEST['province'],
                        $_REQUEST['postal'], $_REQUEST['country'], $_REQUEST['phone'], $_REQUEST['email'], $_REQUEST['newsletter']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    //retrieve values and display in table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registered_users";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              
    if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Data stored in database successfully.<br /><br />
          <table><tr>
          <th>User ID</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Street Address</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Province</th>
          <th>Postal Code</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
          <th>Email Address</th>
          <th>Newsletter Sub</th>
          </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["user_id"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["title"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["firstName"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["lastName"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["street"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["city"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["province"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["postal"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["country"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["phone"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["email"]. "</td>" . 
                 "<td>" . $row["newsletter"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";        
    } else {
        echo "There are 0 results.";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

A var_dump shows that all my variables are NULL.  Blank records are being recorded in the database.  I've also rewritten my bind statement in the following format, but had no luck with that either.

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$province = $_POST['province'];
$postal = $_POST['postal'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssi", $title, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $province, $postal, $country, $phone, $email, $newsletter);
```

If I write and declare values explicitly like this, they write to the database properly which seems to indicate my prepared statement works properly.

```
$title = "Ms";
$firstName = "Jane";
$lastName = "Doe";
$street = "123 ABC Lane";
$city = "AnyTown";
$province = "Nova Scotia";
$postal = "A1A 1A1";
$country = "Canada";
$phone = "555-555-5555";
$email = "email@domain.com";
$newsletter = 1;

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssi", $title, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $province, $postal, $country, $phone, $email, $newsletter);
```

I'll be very grateful for any help in diagnosing why everything seems to work except getting the values through POST. Also willing to accept any tips about why my error-checking seems to get skipped over when submitting to the database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, the seond piece of code you've shown is the `regdatabase.php` file, is that correct? It isn't 100% clear, would be helpful if you could edit the question to label the code snippets as to which file they come from. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway if my assumption is correct, then none of the error-checking code you've written ever gets used because the form posts back directly to regdatabase.php, which doesn't contain any error-checking code - it just tries to write whatever is (or isn't) submitted in the form data directly to the database. The `if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {`.... bit of your first page is never used because the form data is never sent there.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why if you _do_ submit some data, it still saves blank info into the database - that shouldn't be happening according to the code you've shown, as far as I can see.

Comment: @ADyson Updated the code to indicate where the snippets are from.  You're correct the second piece is regdatabase.php.

As for the action re-directing to regdatabase, good catch.  I had that in there early on and forgot to remove it to have the page just post back to itself.  However, now I don't seem to be getting anything written to the database at all.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I note you've now changed the "action" method of your form to "". That should enable the error checking, but it will stop the form data ever being submitted - this part: `else {
//redirect to database
    header("Location: regdatabase.php");
    exit;
}` won't work as you want. A redirect header tells the browser to start a new request to the server, and it's a GET request too, not a POST. So since it's new it won't include any of the form data you just submitted. Instead you really need to put the db-writing code into a function and just call it from that location.

Comment: As a separate aside, your `CREATE TABLE` statement will never do anything because you never send it to the database. But it shouldn't be necessary to have it there anyway - there should never be a scenario where your PHP code is deployed to an environment without the necessary database having also been deployed to the environment correctly beforehand. If that were to occur, it's a failure of your deployment/installation process, which isn't something your application code needs to take account of.

Comment: I'm aware the CREATE TABLE section is irrelevant. It had to be there for the assignment so that my instructor could see I know the proper syntax. I suppose I can edit it out of my code here for clarity's sake though.

Going through the code with a friend, he caught a logic error that I think was responsible for it not posting to the database in the **if ( $errors == 0 ) {** which should be **if ( $errors != 0 ) {** as the else part of that if was the redirect to the database.  So I was only writing if there were errors, including blank lines.  

Thanks for your help @ADyson!

Comment: Ah well spotted, I hadn't noticed that, but it makes sense.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).